# Finding $\gcd$ in the ring of integers

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory

Let $p$ be a prime number, $p\neq 2,13$. Suppose that $p$ divides an integer of the form $a^2+13b^2$, where $a,b$ are integers and coprime.

> I want to show that $p=\gcd(p^2,a^2+13b^2)$.

I think there are only two possibilities, namely: $\gcd=p$ or $\gcd=p^2$. So suppose it is $p^2$ and look for a contradiction. By $p^2$ dividing $a^2+13b^2$ we get that $p$ divides $a+b\sqrt{-13}$ hence $p$ divides both $a$ and $b$ contradicting coprimality.

Do you think my argument be correct? By the way, was it necessary to suppose $p\neq 2,13$?

Comment: Were you allowed to assume that $\Bbb Z[\sqrt{-13}]$ is a [unique factorization domain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unique_factorization_domain)?

Comment: @Lord_Farin it is not an UFD, for example: $14=2\cdot 7=(1+\sqrt{-13})\cdot(1-\sqrt{-13})$

Comment: Then how would you prove $p \mid xy$ implies $p \mid x$ or $p \mid y$ for $x,y \in \Bbb Z[\sqrt{-13}]$ (on which your argument rests critically)? (Edited.)

Comment: @Lord_Farin $p,a,b$ are in $\mathbb{Z}$

Comment: @bateman: That doesn't matter. $a^2,b^2 > 0 $

Comment: @Inceptio Sorry, i can't understand, what doesn't matter?

Comment: $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}$ doesn't matter cause $a^2, b^2 >0 \implies a^2, b^2 \in \mathbb{N}$. Right?

Comment: @Inceptio Yes, now it's clear, i can't deduce that $p$ divides $a+b\sqrt{-13}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $\Bbb Z[\sqrt{-13}]$ is not a UFD -- e.g. $2\cdot 7 = (1+\sqrt{-13})(1-\sqrt{-13})$ -- your approach is not valid.

As a testament thereof, consider $2^2+13\cdot 3^2 = 4 +117 = 121 = 11^2$.

---

That the approach is not valid is because we don't have $p \mid xy$ implies $p \mid x$ or $p \mid y$ if our ring is not a UFD.